# RDLC Reports, how can i rotate objects?

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, rdlc

I have a graph control in my .rdlc report, which have input of some sort of data. Everything is working fine, but now i want to present it rotated by 90 degrees and expanded over whole page, which driving me crazy. I don't see any option of switching axis. Simple rotation option isn't even there.

How can i get the result of rotated chart in .rdlc reports?

Comment: what is the specific graph control you are using so I can possibly test with.  If you are doing with the native "Chart" control for reports, I too do not see any such rotation / transform option.

Comment: yes, it's native control. I need to get the rotation effect independently from way/effort